# Bayes Theorem,probability

Tags: bayes-theorem

An urn contains n balls each identical in size and texture but with different colors. One of the balls is white. Two independent observers, each having a probability of 0.1 of telling the truth, assert that a ball drawn at random from the urn is white.  Prove The probability that the ball is in fact white is (n-1)/(n+80).

I have proceeded as this:
E1: Event that both observers are telling the truth
E2: both are lying

E: A white draw is reported

p(E/E1) =1/n P(E/E2)=n-1/n P(e1)=1/100 P(E2)=811/100. Hence probablity that a white ball was drwan given that a white draw was reported was p(E1/E)= P(e/E1)*P(E1)/P(e/e1)*p(e1)+P(e/e2)*p(e2).. but i am not arriving at the answer..where am i going wrong?

Comment: you should consider the event that one tells the truth and the other not.

Comment: Hi Emanuele...thanks for your suggestion..i am not able to figure out how to construct the the events that will take that possibility into acouunt ..if i define E: 1st observer is telling the truth, i cant figure out to calculate p(E/E3)..thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability both are lying may be $\frac{81}{100}$ but they need not report "white" when lying as there are $n-1$ possible colours they could each say when lying.

Indeed, if the actual colour is not-white and they are both lying, the conditional probability that a particular one of them says "white" is $\frac{1}{n-1}$ and so that both say "white" is $\left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^2$.  You need to include the conditional probability that they both actually say "white" in your calculation, making it

$$ \dfrac {\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{100} \times 1 }{\frac{1}{n}\times \frac{1}{100}\times 1 \;+\; \frac{n-1}{n}\times \frac{81}{100}\times \left(\frac{1}{n-1}\right)^2  } $$

and this will give the expected answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Henry..helped to clear a lot of related concepts